# Trigger for IsChecked does not Trigger

Tags: wpf, data-binding, triggers

I want to change the Icon of a ToggleButton (Content of [Fluent RibbonBar](http://fluent.codeplex.com/)) Depending on it's IsChecked Property. Now I have written the following style snippet:

```
<Fluent:ToggleButton.Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource RibbonButtonStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Fluent:ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Fluent:ToggleButton}}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Style.Images.Pined}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Fluent:ToggleButton}}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Style.Images.Unpined}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Fluent:ToggleButton.Style>
```

The problem is that the Trigger doesn't load the Image well. The problem is not, that IsChecked doesn't actualize itself, I've already tested this. And also I don't set the icon property anywhere else. The image resources also works fine if I use them otherwhere.

Information for Rebuild: I've put the ToggleButton into the Backstage as the DataTemplate of a RibbonListBox placed in a BackstageTabItem.

Comment: You're not setting the Icon property directly elsewhere? In that case the `Setter`s won't work.

Comment: Only directly in the ToggleButton declaration... I'll try out.

Comment: No. removing "Icon=" from the Element Declaration didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **absolutely need** to remove the `Icon` property from the control declaration as it will override everything a style tries to do due to [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

But those `DataTriggers` will not work, the binding will look for an ancestor, **itself excluded**, so you must change them as well as already pointed out by AndrewS. Only if both conditions are met you have a chance of getting this to work (there may be even additional interferences though).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a style for togglebutton you don't need a findancestor binding - you would use self. And actually since `IsChecked` is a DP you can just use a trigger - eg `<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">`